# UISelectionFeedbackGenerator() not working on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios10, haptic-feedback

I would like to use some haptic in my app. I am using the `UISelectionFeedbackGenerator` but it will not work. I am testing on real iPhone 7 with iOS 10. These two lines should do the magic – but nothing happens:

```
let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
generator.selectionChanged()
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I'm in the same boat here. In one of my viewcontrollers, haptic feedback refuses to work. In another, it works even without prepare. I cannot for the life of me understand what's going on.

Answer (score 8):

It seems as if `AVFoundation` (or probably just `AVCaptureSession`) is somehow messing with the haptic feedback! Without `AVFoundation`, my haptic feedback works. As soon as I put it in there, it stops working.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some alternatives that work on older devices:

```
import AudioToolbox

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) // Actuate `Peek` feedback (weak boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520) // Actuate `Pop` feedback (strong boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1521) // Actuate `Nope` feedback (series of three weak booms)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you call `selectionChanged()`, you need to call `generator.prepare()`. This wakes up the taptic engine. It will stay active for a matter of seconds though, so make sure you `prepare()` it again if you're going to call `selectionChanged()` down the road.

```
let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
generator.prepare()
generator.selectionChanged()
```

Comment: I am sure I've tried prepare(), too. I will give it another try and report. Thanks!

Comment: I do not get that to work. Since i am builing an App with target for iOS 9 I'm wrapping these lines in `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { ... }`. But also for iOS 10 without the condition it will not work on my iPhone 7. That was also excatly what I was trying before I posted on stackoverflow.

Comment: Odd. Do you have an accessibility setting on the phone level that disables taptics? Have you tried using a date picker or moving a table view cell in an Apple stock app to ensure you're feeling their taptics?

Comment: It is more than strange. After I capture an image within my app it works (capturing an image and the haptic button have nothing to do with each other – haptic is not bind on the capture button). When I rebuild the app the haptic feedback do not work until I capture an image again. Are there limitations on haptic feedback when using `AVCaptureSession`?

Comment: @KevinLieser I have problem with haptic feedback and AVFoundation aswell!

Answer (score 1):

For those who is struggling with `AVFoundation`, there is a method starting from `iOS13`

```
func setAllowHapticsAndSystemSoundsDuringRecording(_ inValue: Bool) throws
```

You can enable system sounds and haptics play while recording from audio input.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/3240576-setallowhapticsandsystemsoundsdu)

Answer (score 0):

For who using `AVFoundation` and doesn't work with haptic, I found a simple way that makes haptic works with `AVFoundation` simultaneously：

```
func yourAVRecording() {
    // Haptic
    let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
    generator.prepare()
    generator.selectionChanged()

    // Record after played Haptic (just give few time to let haptic done and then magic happen)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
        // Do your AVFoundation stuffs whatever here
    }
}
```